# Evaluate how far away a matrix is from unity

Tags: matrices

I have a mathematical issue I suspect to be one of those very common issues. I have a $N \times M$ matrix which I want to get statistics from. The ideal case is that every row and every column contains one 1. What I want to know is how far away my matrix is from this ideal case. 
Is there some standardized measurement that returns a value that represents how close my matrix is to a unity matrix? (The $1$'s arn't strictly positioned at the diagonal but that can be fixed simply by rearranging the rows / columns based on the "center of gravity" of each row)

Comment: you can use the least square norm $tr(^tAA)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the $p$ norm of your choice.

**Square**

Given $\mathbf{A}\in\mathbb{R}^{m\times m}$, the distance you seek is
$$
  d = \lVert \mathbf{A} - \mathbf{I}_{m} \rVert_{p}
$$

**Rectangular**

For $\mathbf{A}\in\mathbb{R}^{m\times n}$, $m\neq n$ the distance is
$$
  d = \lVert \mathbf{A}\mathbf{A}^{*} - \mathbf{I}_{m} \rVert_{p}
$$

Comment: Yep, that was exactly the term I looked for. :)